# position background image on flexible navigation

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I've got a tricky problem trying to position an image on an active menu item on wordpress. The  html is spat out by wordpress so I can't change the classes I'm presented with I've managed to create a nice flexible menu but I can't seem to get control over the positioning of this image.

This is what I'm trying to achieve > http://i48.tinypic.com/1pyzqo.png

Below is the HTML and here is a fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/rafoggin/cwA7Y/1/

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="menu-main-navigation-container"> 

<ul id="main-menu" class="item-list inline links small">

<li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-54"><a href="http://richardfoggin.co.uk/pinkfloyd/about">About</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-55 current_page_item menu-item-57"><a href="http://richardfoggin.co.uk/pinkfloyd/">Portfolio</a></li>

<li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42"><a href="http://richardfoggin.co.uk/pinkfloyd/blog">Blog</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>​
```

And the CSS:

```
nav#navigation {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; width:100%; 
    padding:20px 0 0; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

nav#navigation ul#main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

nav#navigation ul#main-menu li{
 display: inline-block;
}

nav#navigation ul#main-menu a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 9px;
}


li.current_page_item a {
    background: url(http://richardfoggin.co.uk/pinkfloyd/wp-content/themes/svbtle/images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
}
```

I've tried a :after pseudo-element on the li.current_page_item a class but this didn't hit the mark. But stuck about how to do this, any help would be much appreciated as always :)

R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:after`, but you need to combine it with absolute positioning. You also need to give this positioned item a size.

```
nav#navigation ul#main-menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    position:relative;   <--- you need this 
}

li.current_page_item a:after {
    background: url(http://richardfoggin.co.uk/pinkfloyd/wp-content/themes/svbtle/images/menu-bg.png);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;      
    position:absolute;
    content: "";
    top:16px;
    left:30px;
    width:18px;
    height:20px;   
}
```

Comment: Ahh so because I wasn't giving it a size there was nothing to position? Either way Brilliant!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Ah the bugger isn't centered under the link now..what a cruel world lol!